# Could not execute Node.js Cloud9

Tags: cloud9-ide

I am trying to use Cloud9 IDE on a server. I added the SSH key and once I try to SSH into the server the error message

```
Could not execute node.js on root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

appears.

I have nodejs installed on the server, v0.10.25

Answer (score 7):

You need to install the package "nodejs-legacy".

`apt-get install nodejs-legacy`

Answer (score 5):

The SSH dialog allows you to set the path to the Node.js binary. That should solve your issue.

Comment: Where can I find that binary? I couldn't find any file named node.js using the find command and googling the result does not bring up much useful information

Comment: can you try `which node` to see whether node is installed?

Answer (score 3):

I found it is necessary to scroll down and click on the advanced tab. Then I entered /usr/bin/nodejs from my "which nodejs" output in my SSH session. This worked for me even though the documentation states AWS tries to do this by default. That left me in the AWS file work space on the server I ssh'ed into as desired.

Answer (score 3):

nodejs was not installed on my EC2 instance, so I installed using the instructions from the following link, and it work perfectly. [Tutorial: Setting Up Node.js on an Amazon EC2 Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html)

Comment: but which value you fill in the Node.js binary path - Optional?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install nodejs` worked for me